# How to assign a material to ColladaLoader or OBJLoader

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have looked through the documentation as well as many examples and wasn't able to find correct syntax for assigning a material to either a Collada .dae or OBJLoader .obj file.

Json files seem to properly work when creating a `Mesh` and having the loader as geometry and material as the set material.

Code like this works

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "modelPath.js", function(geometry){
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x666666});
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

This does not work

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load( "modelPath.dae", function(geometry){
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x666666});
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

And this does not work

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( "modelPath.obj", function(geometry){
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x666666});
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

I have also tried `geometry.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xff0000});` inside `function(geometry)` without success.

.Dae format seems to keep material color directly from 3D programs like Cinema. How can I set a material to these loaders properly? If this is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this pattern for `OBJLoader`:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

loader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x666666 } );

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material = material;

        }

    } );

    scene.add( object );

} );
```

For `ColladaLoader`, the pattern is similar.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

loader.load( 'model.dae', function ( collada ) {

    var dae = collada.scene;
    scene.add( dae );

} );
```

three.js r.62

Comment: I get the error, `TypeError: collada.traverse is not a function`
`collada.traverse( function ( child ) {`

Comment: The reference to the mesh was incorrect in my code, your answer is a working solution.