# How to add shader to THREE.Object3D loaded from STLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader, stl-format

I have a model loaded using THREE.STLLoader.

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var mesh = event.content;
    scene.add(mesh);
});
loader.load('model/test.stl');
```

I need to apply a vertex and fragment shader to this model. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A usual way to include your shaders is to put them in `<script>` tags:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    void main() {
        ...
    }

</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    void main() {
        ...
    }

</script>
```

Then, in your `init` function:

```
// it's useful to have uniforms as a ~global variable,
// so you can modify them from other functions
// in animate() or render() for example
var uniforms = {
    // here, your shader's uniforms variables
};

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
});
```

And in your loader callback

```
var mesh = event.content;
mesh.material = material;
```

Have a look to this simple shader example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shader.html

Answer (score 0):

This question does not show any amount of own research effort. 
See this: [How to assign a material to ColladaLoader or OBJLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555369/how-to-assign-a-material-to-colladaloader-or-objloader)

Only three days old. Maybe next time, try to search at least for more than 3 seconds *rollingEyes*. And yeah, there are a lot of examples to check out, as Vincent suggested.