# ThreeJS - How can I apply an environment map to an imported obj model?

Tags: 3d, three.js, blender

**EDIT:** I have come across a solution on this post -- [How to assign a material to ColladaLoader or OBJLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555369/how-to-assign-a-material-to-colladaloader-or-objloader). I used the following code which achieved the effect of allowing me to use the envMaterial cubemap on the imported .obj -

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    loader.load( 'models/refTestblend.obj', function ( object ) {

      object.traverse( function ( child ) {

          if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

              child.material = envMaterial;

          }

      } );

      scene.add( object );

    } );
```

Unfortunately, I have had to sacrifice the .mtl file however, so the next step in my quest will be to attempt to reinstate the exported .mtl textures and somehow mix this will the cubemap material. ( I'm marking this as answered, any further input obviously welcome.. )

**EDIT**: The solution to this issue of mixing the original texture and envmap comments see below. Hope this is of use!

**OP:**
I have an environment cubemap exported from blender - I can apply the envmap to generated geometry fine, but how do I apply it to my imported .obj model?

I believe the closest example I can find it this demo - http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap.html

```
loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
loader.load( "obj/walt/WaltHead_bin.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, cubeMaterial1, cubeMaterial2, cubeMaterial3 ) } );
```

However it runs off the BinaryLoader, which I don't believe I can use with blender exports - (I may be wrong?)

This is what my loader, envmap/skybox, and working gen'd cube looks like..

```
    var urls = [
        'models/cubemap/right.png',
        'models/cubemap/left.png',
        'models/cubemap/top.png',
        'models/cubemap/bottom.png',
        'models/cubemap/front.png',
        'models/cubemap/back.png'
    ];


    // create the cubemap
    var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
    cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    // create a custom shader
    var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
    shader.uniforms["tCube"].value = cubemap;

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

        fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
        vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
        uniforms: shader.uniforms,
        depthWrite: false,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide

    });

    // create the skybox
    var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000), material);
    scene.add(skybox);

    var envMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({envMap:cubemap});

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, envMaterial);
    cube.name = 'cube';
    scene.add(cube);
    cube.position.set(-10, 0, 0);

    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load("models/refTestblend.obj",
    "models/refTestblend.mtl",
    function(obj) {
    obj.translateY(-3);
    scene.add(obj);
    });
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What does THREE.OBJMTLLoader return? If its a Mesh you should be able to switch the material after loading to your envMaterial.

Comment: If not you could export from Blender using the Three plugin and load geometry on its own using the jsonloader, then apply the envMaterial

Comment: The objmtl loader brings in the model nicely, I believe as a mesh, I don't know how to manually apply the envMaterial once it is in? I can adjust the textures loaded in the .mtl file but as far as applying the cubemap I'm lost. 

Ultimately I'll want to have the textures used in the .mtl file in conjunction with the envmap as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an environment map to the existing materials of your OBJ model using a pattern like this one:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    loader.load( 'myModel.obj', function ( object ) {

      object.traverse( function ( child ) {

          if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

              child.material.envMap = myEnvironmentMap;
              // add any other properties you want here. check the docs.

          }

      } );

      scene.add( object );

    } );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for weighing in here. I am using OBJMTLLoader as I haven't been able to find a decent example loading multiple textures from a corresponding .mtl file separately. So the loader looks like loader.load( 'myModel.obj','myModel.mtl'. When I use child.material.envMap it just makes the objects in the scene which are textured, go black? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Well I read through as many documents as I could find and played around with a bunch of examples and I still couldn't get it, I am reading the three.js cookbook so hopefully that will also shed some light. I have come up with a solution which is to load the model twice, increase the size of one very slightly and apply the envmap to that and reduce the transparency. This gives it the exact effect I'm after, however involves loading two fairly heavy models, which won't really be workable down the line.

Comment: Provide a live link to the code that you think should work. Provide an image of what you want the rendering to look like.

Comment: Hi, here is the image which represents the successful result - this was achieved by overlaying two models as described in my previous comment, you can see the (translucent) env map is layered on top of the image textures. http://chriscarruthers.co.uk/dev/demo/result.jpg. Here is the example code http://chriscarruthers.co.uk/dev/demo/example.html comments are inline, it shows the original working version and then the version where I attempt to mix the env map in using traverse, and it bugs out. It isn't shown here but I've tried adding parameters to the material to mix/combine it with no luck.

Comment: `child.material.envMap` should be assigned a cubemap texture, not a material. Also check your console errors/warnings.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for breaking this down for me, really appreciate it!