# Apply a dynamic environment map ( cubeCamera generated ) to an imported obj, and blend with object textures

Tags: 3d, three.js, blender, .obj

By using the following code I am able to create a environment map and apply this to an imported .obj model. *Crucially, this method blends the envMap and models original textures.*

```
    var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
    cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    ....

    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load( 'models/testEnvWalls.obj','models/testEnvWalls.mtl', function ( walls ) {
         walls.traverse( function ( child ) {
             if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material.envMap = cubemap;
             }
         } );
         scene.add( walls );
```

I have created another *dynamic* environment map using cubeCamera, in order to take into account the objects in the scene, such as the model itself, with the following code.

```
    cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 20000, 1024);
    cubeCamera.renderTarget.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
    scene.add(cubeCamera);
    cubeCamera.position.x = 0;
    cubeCamera.position.y = 0;
    cubeCamera.position.z = 20;
```

My problem is that I was able to apply the initial 'static' cubemap and blend it with the original materials, however the results of the cubeCamera envMap generation creates a material, ie..

```
var dynamicEnvMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```

When I apply the material it does not blend with the original textures materials, just 'overwrites' them, the same issue I had with the static envMap, which I overcame by including it as a cubemap.

How do I apply the dynamic environment map, in conjunction with the existing object textures? Can I somehow create a cubemap using cubeCamera.renderTarget for example?

(In theory I feel like it should be straight forward, but I tried a range of hacks and solutions to get the static map blending in with no success until using the cubemap method.)

*Note: A precursor to this question is here, which explains how to achieve the effect of blending a regular cubemap with an imported objects original textures -
[ThreeJS - How can I apply an environment map to an imported obj model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283963/threejs-how-can-i-apply-an-environment-map-to-an-imported-obj-model)*