# three.js OBJLoader callback not executing

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying to load an .obj model generated in Blender and then trying to apply a code-generated reflective material to it.  I am trying to use the pattern described here: [How to assign a material to ColladaLoader or OBJLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555369/how-to-assign-a-material-to-colladaloader-or-objloader), but in my code the callback never executes. My code is as follows:

```
<html>                                                                                                             
  <head>                                                                                                           
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">                                                                                                               
    <style>                                                                                                        
      body{                                                                                                        
        margin: 0;                                                                                                 
        overflow: hidden;                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                            
    </style>                                                                                                       
  </head>                                                                                                          
  <body>                                                                                                           
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1920" height="2059" style="width: 1920px; height: 2059px;"></canvas>              

    <script src="js/three.js"></script>                                                                            
    <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>                                                                        
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>                                                                    

    <script>                                                                                                       
      var renderer, scene, loader, camera, controls;                                                               

      init();                                                                                                      
      animate();                                                                                                   

      function init() {                                                                                            
        //SCENE                                                                                                    
        scene = new THREE.Scene();                                                                                 
        //CAMERA                                                                                                   
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );              
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);                                                                             
        scene.add(camera);                                                                                         
        //RENDERER                                                                                                 
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({                                                                       
          canvas: myCanvas,                                                                                        
          antialias: true                                                                                          
        });                                                                                                        
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);                                                                          
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);                                                           
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);                                                   
        //LIGHT                                                                                                    
        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);                                                                
        var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);                                                               
        light.position.set(0, -1, 3).normalize();                                                                  
        light2.position.set(0, 1, -3).normalize();                                                                 
        scene.add(light);                                                                                          
        scene.add(light2);                                                                                         
        //CONTROLS                                                                                                
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );                                         
        controls.enableDamping = true;                                                                             
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;                                                                             
        controls.screenSpacePanning = false;                                                                       
        controls.minDistance = 10;                                                                                 
        controls.maxDistance = 10;                                                                                 
        controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI;               
        //LOAD MODEL
        loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        console.log("pre-callback");                                                                            
        loader.load('kc.obj', function ( object ) {                                                            
          console.log("callback");                                                                                     
          var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x666666 } );                                     
          object.traverse( function ( child ) {                                                                    
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {                                                                   
              child.material = material;                                                                           
            }                                                                                                      
          } );                                                                                                     
          scene.add( object );                                                                                     
        });   
      }                                                                                                            

      function animate(){                                                                                          
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );                                                                          
        render();                                                                                                  
        controls.update();                                                                                         
      }                                                                                                            

      function render() {                                                                                                                                                            
        renderer.render(scene, camera);                                                                            
      }                                                                                                            
    </script>                                                                                                      
  </body>                                                                                                          
</html>
```

The console does not report any errors.  "pre-callback" is outputted but "callback" is not.  The model is in the root directory of the project.  I'm using Firefox and serving the page from a Node http-server, so it isn't the CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? Chrome does not allow loading of assets in your hard-drive due to same-origin security concerns. However, Firefox does allow it:

[image]

You can see that Firefox has a few `console.log`s that get executed on completion.

To learn how to run things locally on any browser, without CORS concerns, see [How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) in the Three.js documentation.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and I am serving the page via a Node server, so I don't think that's the problem.  I was able to load and display the model as GLTF, but I want to add a material programmatically to the model so I'm trying .obj format.

Comment: Shouldn't the loader log an error to the console if it can't find the model?  Even if I put an invalid model path in the loader.load call there is no error.  Weird.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. Is your Network tab showing any progress? Maybe you could add an `onProgress` and `onError` callback to see if anything is happening, like in this example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html#L118

Comment: I just tried that, onError is not triggered, and onProgress is called once.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Object was in the wrong folder.  I can't believe that was it the whole time.  I must have placed it in the wrong directory when exporting it in the new format.  Thanks!